# Combining multiple year yield data in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1

I am using ArcGIS 10.1 for Desktop and trying to find the simplest way to combine multiple year of crops yield data into one file and get the average yield.

The files are point files from a yield monitor.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Merge](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000055000000) tool on your point files to get one file. Then [Summary Statistics](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00080000001z000000) on your field in question. This should give you the mean, and more.